# No provider for [object Object] after build?

Tags: angular

I get this error after build:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[e -> e -> e -> e -> [object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object]]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for [object Object]!
```

I try to replace default class to custom:

```
@NgModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: OverlayContainer, useExisting: new CustomOverlayContainer(DOCUMENT) }
      ]
})
```

What do I do wrong?

```
export class CustomOverlayContainer extends OverlayContainer {
    constructor(@Optional() @Inject(DOCUMENT) _document: any) {
        super(_document);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you miss the @Injectable decorator?

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
@NgModule({
  providers: [
        { provide: OverlayContainer, useExisting: new CustomOverlayContainer(DOCUMENT) }
      ]
})
```